# How to process large data into PDF in background on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

Currently, I am working on generating large data into PDF using Laravel Mpdf. This works for me at localhost by increasing maximum execution time and backtrack_limit but on the live server, it's not working. I increase these limitations but it gives me errors like 'request timeout with 500'. I told the server administrator and they suggest me to edt php.ini but still says the same error. I could not find the proper solution.

Another problem is that when generating PDF the other browsing staff are stuck until the PDF making process is finished. I searched on google and youtube but not getting a proper solution. I have also used chunking but it gives the same error.

Is there any way to do above staffs in the background by implementing laravel jobs? If yes then how to implement jobs for making pdf in background where other pages will be working fine. I know basic job implementation in laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found a solution. I can make large pdf using laravel queue jobs and chunking the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Job-Queue to process your data in background, and in the background after the queue will complete to generate your desire output show an alert or message in frontend.

here is some resource for you.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues